# How to use threads with a recursive template function

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, c++11

I've been trying to optimize a sorting algorithm (quicksort) with threads. I know it is already quite good in the std::sort() implementation, but I'm trying to beat it with optimizations on my computer, and learn about threads at the same time.

So, my question is, how do I use threads with my recursive quicksort function?

Here's the function (with the not-important-to-the-question stuff removed):

```
template <typename T>
void quicksort(T arr[], const int &size, const int &beginning, const int &end)
{
    // Algorithm here
    thread t1(quicksort, arr, size, beginning, slow - 1);
    thread t2(quicksort, arr, size, slow + 1, end);
}
```

If I was wrong and you do end up needing more of the code, let me know and I'll update it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and as of right now, the error states:

```
error C2661: 'std::thread::thread' : no overloaded function takes 5 arguments
```

I've also tried calling ref(arr), etc. on each of the parameters, but I got the same error.

EDIT:
After trying the solution by @mfontanini I can compile with no errors, but on running, I get:

```
Debug Error!

Program: ...sktop\VisualStudio\Projects\SpeedTester\Debug\SpeedTester.exe

R6010
- abort() has been called


(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

Repeated over an over again. Eventually, it exits with code 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem probably is that you need to `join()` the `thread`(s) you spawn. If the thread objects are destructed without a prior `join()` or `detach()` the implementation calls `std::terminate()`.

You don't want `detach()`, as you need to know that all partial sorts are finished for the overall sort to be complete, so `join`ing is the right thing to do.

Additionally there are a few more things you could improve:

- You should not pass around `int`s by reference. Pass by value is more efficient for simple scalar types and referencing local variables from other threads is generally not a good idea (unless you have a good reason and protocol for it)
- You start far too many threads. After partitioning you need two threads for the two sub-sorts, but you have three: the current thread also continues to run, so you should create just one new thread and do the other sub-sort in the current thread. (And `join()` the other part when done.)
- You should not keep creating new threads when the partitions get small. It may generally be a good idea to have a cutoff size for your quicksort and use something non-recursive (like insertion sort) for smaller sizes, as the recursion overhead becomes higher than the algorithm complexity benefit. A similar cut-off is even more important for concurrent sorting: the overhead of a thread is much higher than a simple recursive call and with small (and nearby) partitions, the threads will start to hit the same cache lines frequently, slowing things down even more.
- It is generally not a good idea to create threads without limit. That will eventually run  into platform limits. You might want to restrict the count of threads to use (using an atomic counter) or use something like `std::async` with default launch policy to avoid launching more threads than the platform can handle.

Comment: Thank you! This with @mfontanini got my code running. And thanks for the extra information as well! I'll definitely keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly indicate which is the `T` template parameter:

```
thread t1(&quicksort<T>, arr, size, beginning, slow - 1);
```

Otherwise the compiler sees that you're referring to a function template, but not to which specific specialization; it can't deduce `T` out of nowhere.