# Creating Threads inside recursive function

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion

I have an app with some recursive function that in general looks like this:

```
threads = 0;
Algorithm(array) {
    //some code...

    newArray1 = array.Take(array.Length / 2).ToArray();
    newArray2 = array.Skip(array.Length / 2).ToArray();

    ThreadStart start1 = delegate
        {
            Algorithm(newArray1);
        };

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(start1);

    ThreadStart start2 = delegate
        {
            Algorithm(newArray2);
        };

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(start2);
    thread1.Start();
    threads++;
    thread2.Start();
    threads++;
}
```

It doesn't matter how deep this recursion goes, the variable **threads** always equals 2. Why?

Comment: Because both threads share the same variable `threads`

Comment: @user3185569 so the scope doesn't matter for threads?

Comment: You're not setting the common variable as a [Mutual exclusion section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion). 

This can make some inconsistence solution, so as a good practise any shared variable should be in a mutual exclusion section.

And when you wait/join you threads to syncronize it?

Comment: What scope ? They both share the same variable and you have a race condition there. It all depends on when are you examining the value of `threads`. try `Thread.Sleep(5000)` before starting the second thread and print the value of `threads` inside each delegate, you might very likely get `1` and `2` as outputs.

Comment: What kind of type is this inside? I am assuming that `threads` is a field of a surrounding type, is that correct? If so, can you show the declaration of this type?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen simple `public int threads = 0;`

Comment: And the type it is in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you were not waiting for the threads to finish. You would need to add inside your `Algorithm` method a call to `Thread.Join()` method ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.110).aspx)), which "blocks the calling thread until the thread represented by this instance terminates" (you would do this for both `thread1` and `thread2`). Also, you would need to use `Interlocked` class which "provides atomic operations for variables that are shared by multiple threads" to increment number of threads (see [Increment method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Having said that, you should keep in mind that creating new Threads for individual tasks is highly inefficient (there is performance overhead with creating threads/context switching). Instead, you should use Thread Pool provided by the CLR. If you want more information on how to use Task Parallelism to efficiently utilize Thread Pool, see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. And one more thing: I've used `thread1.Abort(); thread2.Abort();` in the end of the function. Yeah, I know that it's bad, but I have a question: in debug I can see only two **'ThreadAbortException'** exceptions, but there are 8 levels of recursion that actually happen! 

So there are only 2 Threads that actually exist. Why?

Comment: I would not rely on this exception to find out how many threads were started. Try adding the following code to the beginning of your `Algorithm` method `Console.WriteLine("Current thread id: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` instead

Comment: and do you wait for other threads to finish by calling `Join()`?

Comment: No, I don't. Only start and abort them.

Comment: main thread exits before the other threads finish, which is why you don't see other threads reporting their ID to console

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `threads` variable is shared. Have a look at this link for use of threads with recursive functions - [How to use threads with a recursive template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047929/how-to-use-threads-with-a-recursive-template-function)

Comment: But if the variable is shared, shouldn't the recursiveness increase it *above* 2? There is likely locking and racing issues here but if the OP is right, the variable *always* contains the value 2, then isn't that odd?